# Run javascript to re-bind datepicker after an asp.net Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, datepicker

I have some Ajax that is written onto some controls in my code-behind, one of those controls inside of the `asp:UpdatePanel` is a textbox with a jQuery datepicker widget bound to it. When the Ajax call is triggered and the panel is refreshed, that bound datepicker widget is lost because of the refresh and will need to be re-bound. My question is: are there any methods or ways that I could get some javascript ran again, after the `asp:UpdatePanel` is refreshed?

UPDATE:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    //Here I'm initially binding the datepicker to the txtFirstIllDate control, works great
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%= txtFirstIllDate.ClientID %>').datepicker(({
            startDate: "01/01/1990",
            showOn: "both",
            buttonImage: "Images/calendar_2.png",
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            buttonText: "Select first ill date"
        }));
    });
</script>

<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
                <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblStateID" runat="server" Text="State ID:"></asp:Label><asp:TextBox ID="txtStateID" runat="server" Width="40%" CssClass="floatRight" MaxLength="50"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblFirstIllDate" runat="server" Text="First Ill Date:"></asp:Label><asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstIllDate" runat="server" Width="40%" CssClass="floatRight"></asp:TextBox>                            
                        <asp:Button ID="btnNewReport" runat="server" OnClick="btnNewReport_Click" Text="Create NORS Report" CssClass="marginBottom10px" />
                        <div class="clearFloat">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblErrorReportName" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Font-Bold="true" Visible="false" CssClass="blockItem"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblErrorFirstIll" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Font-Bold="true" Visible="false" CssClass="blockItem"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblErrorEstimatedPrimary" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Font-Bold="true" Visible="false" CssClass="blockItem"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblErrorModeOfTransmission" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Font-Bold="true" Visible="false" CssClass="blockItem"></asp:Label>
                        </div>                            
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>




// Code behind when btnNewReport is pressed
    protected void btnNewReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsValidEntry())
        {
            //After all this code is ran and the panel is updated,
            //the txtFirstIllDate control looses its datepicker widget.
            //How do I get js to run again after the ajax panel update?
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you update your post with your current markup?

Comment: Done, as requested.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET UpdatePanel implements the JavaScript `XMLHttpRequest` object to handle responses from the server with the AJAX functionality.

When you add a ScriptManager and UpdatePanel control in an ASP.NET Page,  internally loads a client script library from Microsoft that it has functions related `XMLHttpRequest` object.

Exists others functions inside (script library from Microsoft) (.axd files).

Every response through ScriptManager - UpdatePanel is processed in the ASP.NET Life-Cycle Events.

You could try with something like this:

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) { // This function name is reservaded in ASP.NET AJAX when you use a ScriptManager in the page.

  $('#<%= txtFirstIllDate.ClientID %>').datepicker(({
    startDate: "01/01/1990",
    showOn: "both",
    buttonImage: "Images/calendar_2.png",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonText: "Select first ill date"
  }));

}
```

You can find more information in this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386417.aspx) (Ajax Client Life-Cycle Events).